# LANG_ENGLISH undefined for MUI when compiling with NSIS 3.0

Tags: windows, nsis, nsis-mui

I just upgraded from [NSIS 2.51](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nsis/files/NSIS%202/2.51/) to [NSIS 3.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nsis/files/NSIS%203/3.0/), mainly because the new version [supports Windows 10](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/AppendixF.html#v3.0).

For my installer I'm using the [Modern User Interface (MUI)](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI/Readme.html). I make use of some custom pages. According to the [documentation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI/Readme.html), I'm using the `MUI_HEADER_TEXT` macro to set the text on the page header in my custom page functions, for example:

```
[...]
Page custom InstallType

LangString PAGE_INSTALL_TYPE_TITLE ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Installation Type"
LangString PAGE_INSTALL_TYPE_SUBTITLE ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Choose installation type."

Function InstallType
    !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT $(PAGE_INSTALL_TYPE_TITLE) $(PAGE_INSTALL_TYPE_SUBTITLE)
    [...]
```

At end of my installer script I also added the following line:

```
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
```

On Windows 7, this compiles without any warning when using NSIS 2.51 (and below). However, when compiling with NSIS 3.0, I get the following warning for each of the `LangString` lines:

> "${LANG_ENGLISH}" is not a valid language id, using language id 1033! [...]

It seems that `LANG_ENGLISH` is no longer defined when using NSIS 3.0. I can get rid of the warning by adding the following line to my installer script:

```
!define LANG_ENGLISH 1033
```

But what am I supposed to do to fix this issue in the correct way for NSIS 3.0?

---

**Minimal, complete, and verifiable example with 4 pages (2 custom pages):**

```
!include "MUI2.nsh"

; Page 1.
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME

; Page 2.
Page custom InstallType

LangString PAGE_INSTALL_TYPE_TITLE ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Installation Type"
LangString PAGE_INSTALL_TYPE_SUBTITLE ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Choose installation type."

Function InstallType
  !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT $(PAGE_INSTALL_TYPE_TITLE) $(PAGE_INSTALL_TYPE_SUBTITLE)
  nsDialogs::Create /NOUNLOAD 1018
  Pop $0
  ${If} $0 == error
    Abort
  ${EndIf}
  ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 4u 100% 12u "Custom page one"
  Pop $0
  nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

; Page 3.
Page custom InstallVersion

LangString PAGE_VERSION_TITLE ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Version"
LangString PAGE_VERSION_SUBTITLE ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Choose version."

Function InstallVersion
  !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT $(PAGE_VERSION_TITLE) $(PAGE_VERSION_SUBTITLE)
  nsDialogs::Create /NOUNLOAD 1018
  Pop $0
  ${If} $0 == error
    Abort
  ${EndIf}
  ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 4u 100% 12u "Custom page two"
  Pop $0
  nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

; Page 4.
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
```

I know, having the `MUI_LANGUAGE` line at the end of the script looks strange. However, I can't put that line earlier into the script, because then I get the following warning:

> MUI_PAGE_* inserted after MUI_LANGUAGE [...]

If I put the `MUI_LANGUAGE` line even before `!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME`, then I also get the following warning:

> MUI_LANGUAGE should be inserted after the MUI_[UN]PAGE_* macros [...]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The warning is new in NSIS 3 but the compiler behavior is unchanged, LANG_ENGLISH is not defined at that point in NSIS 2 either.

The warning gives you a hint about what is going on: When the compiler gets to your `LangString` statements LANG_ENGLISH has not been defined yet so the compiler tries to convert the string `${LANG_ENGLISH}` to a number and that fails and the number conversion function returns 0. If you look at the documentation for `LangString` you see that if you pass 0 as the language id it will use the last used/loaded language. If at this point no languages have been loaded it is left with the default language and that is English.

The LANG_xyz defines are created by the `LoadLanguageFile` instruction when you use it to load xyz.nlf. MUI calls `LoadLanguageFile` inside its `MUI_LANGUAGE` macro so your solution is simply to move the `LangString` statements below the `MUI_LANGUAGE` macro:

```
!include MUI2.nsh

Page Custom MyPageCreate
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

LangString PAGE_INSTALL_TYPE_TITLE ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Installation Type"
LangString PAGE_INSTALL_TYPE_SUBTITLE ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Choose installation type."

Function MyPageCreate
!insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT $(PAGE_INSTALL_TYPE_TITLE) $(PAGE_INSTALL_TYPE_SUBTITLE)
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
${If} $0 == error
    Abort
${EndIf}
${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "Hello world!"
Pop $0
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Thank you, Anders. I had mixed up the MUI `insertmacro` lines, the `LangString` lines, and the page functions. I rearranged everything as you said and now the warning is gone. And the script is still working ;)

Comment: The order is not really that strict, the function has to come after MUI.nsh so MUI_HEADER_TEXT exists and LangString after MUI_LANGUAGE if you are using ${LANG_XYZ}...

Comment: I see. My main problem was that I have three custom pages and had grouped together all commands that belong to a page.

Answer (score 2):

The macro needs to be inserted before you're defining any language strings. Insert the macro right before your language definitions and before the using them.

```
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

LangString PAGE_INSTALL_TYPE_TITLE ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Installation Type"
LangString PAGE_INSTALL_TYPE_SUBTITLE ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Choose installation type."
```

As far as I remember, this isn't any different in NSIS 2 – maybe it's the *warning* that is new.

Comment: I tried to reorder the commands as you suggested. It seems that I have a larger misunderstanding on how order all commands, because now I get: `MUI_LANGUAGE should be inserted after the MUI_[UN]PAGE_* macros`. I had put the MUI defines directly in front of the corresponding page functions, so I will try to move them together before the `MUI_LANGUAGE` line next.